# Display array from child component in parent component react JavaScript

Tags: reactjs

In the code below, I am passing object from the child component (AddContact.js) to the parent component (App.js) to save in the array in the parent component(contacts). My problem is how to display the array in the parent component. Both log button from the child component and the parent component are logging their array content to the console correctly but its not displaying

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import AddContact from './contact/AddContact';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
    const [contacts, AddContacts] = useState([]);
    const Add = (data)=> {
      contacts.push(data);
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <AddContact Add={Add}/>
        <button onClick={()=>console.log(contacts)}>Parent Contacts Log</button>
        <table>
        {
             {/* to display the content of the array here is my problem*/}
            contacts.forEach(contact=>{
                <tr><td>contacts.indexOf(contact)</td><td>contact.name</td><td>contact.email</td></tr>
            })
        }
        </table>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

AddContact.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

function AddContact(props) {
    const [cont, AddCont] = useState({name:' ',email:' '});
    return (
        <div>
            <div><input type='text' placeholder='Please enter your name' onChange={e=>AddCont({...cont,name:e.target.value})} /></div>
            <div><input type='text' placeholder='Please enter your email'  onChange={e=>AddCont({...cont,email:e.target.value})} /></div>
            <button onClick={()=>props.Add(cont)}>Add Contact</button>
            <div><button onClick={()=>console.log(cont)}>Child Cont Log</button></div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default AddContact;
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` do not return anything.

For returning list of components, you can use `map` which `returns array` of components.

---

```
import './App.css';
import AddContact from './contact/AddContact';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
    const [contacts, AddContacts] = useState([]);
    const Add = (data)=> {
      contacts.push(data);
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <AddContact Add={Add}/>
        <button onClick={()=>console.log(contacts)}>Parent Contacts Log</button>
        <table>
        {
             {/* to display the content of the array here is my problem*/}
            contacts.map(contact=>{ //<------ use map here
                return ( //<------- you have to return the component
                        <tr>
                          <td>contacts.indexOf(contact)</td>
                          <td>contact.name</td>
                          <td>contact.email</td>
                        </tr>
            })
        }
        </table>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

For displaying looping `Component` you should use `map` instead of `forEach`.

** Suggestion from me, AVOID using `forEach` for iterating list, instead of using `forEach` you can use `for in` loop. One of reason is `forEach` can't process `Asynchronous` / `await` operation.

```
<table>
    {
        contacts.map((contact, index) => {
          return (
             <tr>
                <td>{index+1}</td>
                <td>{contact.name}</td>
                <td>{contact.email}</td>
             </tr>
          )
        })
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change add function

```
const Add = (data) => {
AddContacts(contacts.concat(data));
console.log(contacts)}
```

And use map

```
contacts.map((contact, index) => {
      return (
         <tr>
            <td>{index}</td>
            <td>{contact.name}</td>
            <td>{contact.email}</td>
         </tr>
      )
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

try this for add function:

```
const Add = (data)=> {
      AddContacts(contacts.concat(data));
    }
```

Comment: "Try this" with no other explanation is rarely a good answer. Please provide an explanation of how your code answers the question.

Comment: if you have good idea please add it. you learn just set minies to every one:)